# What is the Android GSF package?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

What is it the GSF_PACKAGE I found in the C2DM Tutorial?
To be precise:

```
public static final String GSF_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.gsf"
```

It was used in intent:

```
registrationIntent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
```

On the developers site I found this:

> "setPackage(String packageName) (Usually optional) Set an explicit
>   application package name that limits the components this Intent will
>   resolve to."

Anyway, what limits and why they might be needed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`gsf = google services framework`